# Numo::Linalgライブラリを使用したいのですが，RuntimeErrorが出てしまい，原因がわかりません

Tags: ruby, rubygems

数値計算でNumo::Linalgライブラリを使用したいため，以下のようなコードを書きました．
ところが，下記のURLにあるようにBackend Libraryを指定しても下記のようなRuntimeエラーが出てしまいます．
https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-linalg
https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-linalg/blob/master/doc/select-backend.md

エラーメッセージ
``` /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/numo-linalg-0.1.3/lib/numo/linalg/loader.rb:145:in``'load_lapack': cannot find BLAS/LAPABK library (RuntimeError) ```

原因が全くわからないので，どなたかご教授お願い致します．

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'numo/linalg/use/lapack'
require 'numo/linalg/use/openblas'

# Numo 最小二乗法
def NumoLeastSquare(x, y)

  # xの転置行列, yの転置行列 を NArray に変換する（NumRu::Lapack.cgelssの実装上，転置しなければいけない）
  nx = NArray.to_na(x.transpose)
  ny = NArray.to_na(y.transpose)

  # 最小二乗法を解く
  # => || b - Ax || が最小となる x を求める
  # b に上書きされる
  a, b, s, rank, info = Numo::Linalg::Lapack.cgelss(nx, ny, 0.00001.to_f)

  return b
end

class UnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_Numo_lapack_cgelss
    a = [[Complex(2.0, 0.0), Complex(0.0, 0.0)], [Complex(-1.0, 0.0), Complex(1.0, 0.0)], [Complex(0.0, 0.0), Complex(2.0, 0.0)]]
    b = [[Complex(1.0, 0.0)], [Complex(0.0, 0.0)], [Complex(-1.0, 0.0)]]
    h = NumoLeastSquare(a, b)

    p h.size

    for i in 0 ... h.size do
      p "h[#{i}] = #{h[i]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、LAPACK ライブラリがインストールされていないのではないでしょうか？ [Installation](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-linalg#installation) には "Install LAPACK or alternative package" と書かれています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'numo/linalg/use/lapack'
```

の行を削除してはどうでしょうか。

```
require 'numo/linalg/use/openblas'
```

の行だけで実行できるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

[Numo::Linalg](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-linalg)のGitHubの、`README.md`によると、

> Install [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) or alternative package.
>   (LAPACKか互換のパッケージが必要です）

補足として

> Numo::Linalg requires C-interface [CBLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_cblas) and [LAPACKE](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) interface. These are included in LAPACK package.
>   (訳：`Numo::Linalg`はC-インターフェースとしてCLABSとLAPACKEが必要ですが、`LAPACK`に含まれています)

更に

> Recommended: use one of following faster libraries:
>   (訳：ライブラリーを高速に動かすためには以下のいずれかのライブラリーが必要です)

[ATLAS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/math-atlas/)
[OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net)
[Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl)

とあるので、`LAPACK`のインストールが別途必須で、
より処理速度を求める場合には、`ATLAS`,`OpenBLAS`,`Intel MKL`これらのうちいずれかをインストールすれば良いのでは無いでしょうか。

訳が間違っていた場合はご容赦またはご指摘よろしくお願いします。

Comment: MacOSを利用していまして，`brew install lapack`，`brew install openblas`でインストールされていることは確認しているのですが，それでも`RuntimeError`が出ます...

Comment: RubyGemでインストールする方が良い気がします。

Comment: RubyGemでlapackに該当するものが，`Ruby-Lapack`しか確認できなく，これは既にインストール済みです．

Comment: `gem install numo-lapack` はするべきでしょうか？

Comment: 駄目だったら、`gen uninstall <gem名>`でアンインストール出来るので恐れずにやってみましょう。失敗してもそこから何かを学べるものです（って、精神論は駄目ですね）